# Change JavaScript variable depending on selected DropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table that has a lot of `DropDownList` that i had change each of the class name depending on the iteration :

```
<table id="categoryTable" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubCategory)
        </th>
        <th>New Category</th>
        <th>New Subcategory</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @if (Model != null) { int i = 1; foreach (var item in Model) {

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubCategory)
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="varIteration" value="@i" /> @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, "Select Your Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control Category" + i })
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" class=@( "SubCategoryID_CategoryID_initial"+@i) value="@i" /> @Html.DropDownList("SubCategoryId", null, "Select Your Subcategory", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control SubCategory" + i })
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">
                <i class="fa fa-check"> Update</i>
            </button>
            @*
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="fa fa-check" />*@
        </td>
    </tr>
    i++; } }

</table>
```

I need to change the subcategory values depending on the selected value in the Category using the next script below that doesn't work only on time with the first category drop down list:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var iteration = $(".varIteration").val(); // iteration = 1 only
    getSubCat(true, $(".SubCategoryID_CategoryID_initial" + iteration).val(), iteration);
    $(document).on("change", ".Category" + iteration, function(event) {
        getSubCat(false, $(".Category" + iteration).val(), iteration);
    });

    function getSubCat(load, changed, iteration) {
        alert(iteration)
        var url = "/auc.accesscontrol/profiles/GetSubCatIDByCatID";
        var initialSubCat = $(".SubCategoryID_CategoryID_initial").val();
        var initialCat = $(".SubCategoryID_SubCategoryID_initial").val();
        if (load) {
            $('.Category' + iteration + ' option[value="' + initialCat + '"]').prop("selected", true);
        }
        if (initialCat == null) {
            changed = $(".Category" + iteration).val();
        }
        $.getJSON(url, {
            id: changed
        }, function(data) {
            alert(changed);
            $(".SubCategory" + iteration).empty();
            $(".SubCategory" + iteration).append("<option value= '0'>Select Your Subcategory</option>");
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                $(".SubCategory" + iteration).append("<option value='" + item.SubCategoryId + "'>" + item.Name + "</option>");
                $('.SubCategory' + iteration + ' option[value="' + initialSubCat + '"]').prop("selected", true);
            });
        });
    };
});
```

When I check the view class names will find that drop down list for categories like : Category1, Category2 ,...etc
and the Subcategory : SubCategory1, Subcategory2, ....etc
hidden input values : will changed depending on the last `i`.
Need a help to change the iteration variable depending on the selected category drop down list.

**EDIT** :
This is the JsonResult function:

```
public JsonResult GetSubCatIDByCatID(int id)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var subCategoryList = db.SubCategory.Where(m => m.CategoryId == id).ToList();
        return Json(subCategoryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what *specifically* is it doing when you debug this?  Where exactly does the observed behavior not match the expected behavior?

Comment: It's work correctly just with the first drop down list for category and subcategory will filtered correctly ... again just in the first `<tr>`

Comment: iteration variable always equal 1

Comment: Nothings happen when click on any other drop down list

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
$(".varIteration").val()
```

If there are *multiple* matching elements (and in this case there are), what do you expect the *single* value to be?  From the description of the behavior it sounds like it's the value from the *first* matching element.

Get the `iteration` value *in the event*, not at the page level.  So first change your event handler creation to something like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "[class^=Category]", function(event) {
    //...
});
```

This will find all elements where `class` "starts with" `"Category"`, regardless of what the rest of the class name is.

Then, *inside that event handler*, you can dynamically navigate the DOM to find the *specific* `iteration` value you want.  For the HTML you show, that would look something like this:

```
var iteration = $(this).closest("td").find(".varIteration").val();
```

Which basically means:

> Starting from the element which raised the `change` event, navigate up the DOM to the first `<td>` element, then within that element find any matching `.varIteration` elements.

Since within that scope there's only *one* `.varIteration` element, it'll have the value you're looking for.

You'll still need to adjust the call to `getSubCat()`, since that also tries to use that one value.  It's not clear to me what that function is supposed to actually do, so there's only so much I can advise on that.  If it does need to be called for each possible value of `iteration` then you could perhaps put that range of values in a variable somewhere and call `getSubCat()` in a loop.  Though a loop of AJAX calls to the same resource seems pretty inefficient.  I suspect there's a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do with that function.

But at least for the problems you describe in your comments above:

> iteration variable always equal 1

That's because you only ever get one value for it, and it's the first matching value.

> Nothings happen when click on any other drop down list

That's because you only ever create a `change` handler for that one matching value.

Create a single change handler for *all* matching elements and dynamically get the value you need in that change handler instead.

Comment: Thanks @David for your help, but when trying to do the onChange function it's fire just one time when try to debug it using 
`alert($(document).on("change", "[class^=Category]", function (event) {
        var iteration = $(this).closest("td").find(".varIteration").val();

    }));`
without change the selected category class

Comment: also if try to use `alert($("[class^=Category]").val());`  it's get undefined

Comment: @Hansy: None of the things you're trying to do in those comments makes sense, so I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: Check my answer below and will understand what does i mean.

Comment: @Hansy: So you solved it by doing exactly what I suggested in my answer.  Good to know.

Comment: Yes that's true Thank you so much @David

Answer (score -1):

I had Solved it using the below code:
HTML View:

```
        <table id="categoryTable" class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tr class="header">
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubCategory)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @if (Model != null)
        {
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubCategory)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="hidden" id="varIteration" value="@i" />
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.Category, new SelectList(db.Category.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted), "CategoryId", "Name"), "Select Your Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control Category", @id = "Category" + i })
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="hidden" id="SubCategoryID_CategoryID_initial" value="@item.SubCategory" />
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.SubCategory, new SelectList(db.SubCategory.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted), "SubCategoryId", "Name"), "Select Your Subcategory", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SubCategory" + i })
                        </div>
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("    ", "UnifiedAccessCategoryIndex", new { Category = item.Category, Subcategory = item.SubCategory }, new { @class = "fa fa-edit fa-lg" })
                        @*<button type="submit" class="btn">

                                <i class="fa fa-check"> Update</i>
                            </button>*@
                        @*<input type="submit" value="Save" class="fa fa-check" />*@
                    </td>
                </tr>
                i++;
            }
        }

    </table>
```

And inside my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var iteration = null;
    getSubCat(true, $('[class^=SubCategoryID_CategoryID_initial]').val(), iteration);
    $(document).on("change", 'select[id^=Category]', function (event) {
        iteration = $(this).closest("td").find("#varIteration").val();
        getSubCat(false, $('#Category' + iteration).val(), iteration);
    });
});
function getSubCat(load, changed, iteration) {
    var url = "/auc.accesscontrol/profiles/GetSubCatIDByCatID";

    var initialSubCat = $('[id^="SubCategoryID_CategoryID_initial"]').val();
    var initialCat = $('[id^="SubCategoryID_SubCategoryID_initial"]').val();
    if (load) {

        $('#Category' + iteration + ' option[value="' + initialCat + '"]').prop("selected", true);
    }
    if (initialCat == null) {
        changed = $('#Category' + iteration).val();
    }
    $.getJSON(url, { id: changed }, function (data) {
        $('#SubCategory' + iteration).empty();
        $('#SubCategory' + iteration).append("<option value= '0'>Select Your Subcategory</option>");
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            $('#SubCategory' + iteration).append("<option value='" + item.SubCategoryId + "'>" + item.Name + "</option>");
            $('#SubCategory' + iteration + ' option[value="' + initialSubCat + '"]').prop("selected", true);
        });
    });
};
```